# Pandas read_csv() is making more decimal digits than in original csv and thus ruins the sum of rows of dataframe

Tags: dataframe, precision, markov-chains

I have a markov chain related to cancer stored as csv, and each probability is up to **10 decimal digits**,
Now when I am using `pd.read_csv()` form pandas the probabilities actually get more than 10 decimal digits, for example 0.0929190516 becomes after reading csv and printing the dataframe up to 20 decimal digits using `pd.set_option("display.precision", 20)` 0.09291905159999999664.

Now I understand from previous posts that this problem is due to floating problems and maybe there's nothing we can do, but the issue is I am using the rows of the dataframe as probability vectors **(vectors that should sum up to 1 and exactly 1)** in numpy, but because of that previous problem the sum of rows gets slitely different than 1!

Now I've found previous questions where they propose to use `float_precision="round_trip"` to solve this issue, but it didn't work and honestly I tried to modify certain probabilities manually to make sum of rows of dataframe equals 1 but with no hope.

Here's the code that I used and the error I get

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pd.set_option("display.precision", 20)


cancer_dataframe = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer="Cancer Poumon.csv", header=0, engine="c", float_precision="round_trip")

cancer_dataframe.set_index(keys=cancer_dataframe.columns, inplace=True)

print(cancer_dataframe)

if cancer_dataframe.isna().sum().sum() == 0:
    print("\nGood to GO, no NAN values in dataframe. Proceed\n")


drop_index = cancer_dataframe.sum()[cancer_dataframe.sum() == 0].index

cancer_dataframe.drop(index=drop_index, columns=drop_index, inplace=True)


print(cancer_dataframe.sum(axis=1))


# This is what I tried to do to fix the sum of rows and make it equal to 1

# for cancer_type in cancer_dataframe.index:
#     cancer_dataframe.loc["Adrenal", cancer_type] += 1 - cancer_dataframe.sum()[cancer_type]

# print(cancer_dataframe.sum(axis=1))


random_generator = np.random.default_rng()


cancer_mapping = cancer_dataframe.columns.tolist()

limiting_distribution = np.zeros(shape=cancer_dataframe.shape[0], dtype=np.uint32)


for i in range(10_000):

     cancer_type = random_generator.choice(cancer_mapping)
     limiting_distribution[cancer_mapping.index(cancer_type)] += 1
     for j in range(99_999):
         cancer_type = random_generator.choice(cancer_mapping,p=cancer_dataframe.loc[cancer_type])
         limiting_distribution[cancer_mapping.index(cancer_type)] += 1

 limiting_distribution = limiting_distribution / 1e9

cancer_dataframe.loc["limiting distribution"] = limiting_distribution
```

And here's the error I get when executing in Pycharm:

```
 line 45, in <module>
    cancer_type = random_generator.choice(cancer_mapping, p=cancer_dataframe.loc[cancer_type])
  File "_generator.pyx", line 754, in numpy.random._generator.Generator.choice
ValueError: probabilities do not sum to 1
```

To show more about what I mean when sum of lines is slitely different than 1 here's a few lines of results from `print(cancer_dataframe.sum(axis=1))`:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Adrenal | 0.99999999989999999173 |
| Bladder | 1.00000000010000023032 |
| Bone | 0.99999999980000009447 |
| Brain | 0.99999999989999988070 |

Comment: Basis of this problem lies in probabilities not adding up to 1 due to float rounding. I would suggest to check if `cancer_dataframe.columns.tolist()/sum(cancer_dataframe.columns.tolist())` is almost similar to `cancer_dataframe.columns.tolist()`. If it actually is then float rounding are small. As a result you can do `cancer_mapping = cancer_dataframe.columns.tolist()/sum(cancer_dataframe.columns.tolist())` which will ensure that probabilities always sum to 1.

Comment: I don't think your solution quite makes sense, since `sum(cancer_dataframe.columns.tolist())` is trying to sum strings which doesn't make sense, the issue here is in the probabilities (a.k.a the cancer_dataframe values) and how to make **rows all sum up to 1**

Comment: I messed up in reading the code. I meant that probabilities should be normalised. On second reading of the code it looks like probabilities are present in `cancer_dataframe.loc[cancer_type]`. Please normalise those.

Comment: Could you explain more what you mean by **normalize** and provide code if possible. Thank You